# fetchTasks() function does not work when page is reloaded at first

Tags: ethers.js, react, frontend

I have a weird issue. The issue is the fetchTasks() function does not work at first render, so does not display anything on the page, but if i save the code again, does not matter how even if I don't change anything, then the function works and display on the content on the page. This is the function:

```
  const fetchTasks = async () => {
    try {
      const signer = await getProviderOrSigner(true);
      const contract = await contractInstance(signer);
      const query = await contract.getTasks(address);
      console.log("This is the query: ", query);
      setMissions(query);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Query failed", error.message);
    }
  };

  console.log("These are the mission: ", missions);
```

I have never seen like this before. Thanks in advance